# Python tkinter delete listbox column error; self.tk.call(self._w, "delete", items)

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I am new and still learning about Python and SQl. So I follow a tutorial from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Dmh4ZyS2J0&t=2s

At **line **101****, I add a code which are
**listBox.delete(0,END)**, this code is use for the button that have I have created at **line **143****

**Button(root, text="View Latest",command = show,height=3, width= 13).place(x=250+110, y=130)**

When user add or delete or update a data, they can see their latest update they made at the listbox by clicking this button. It will clear the listbox and insert the latest updated database from sql. For some reason I keep on getting this error,
**self.tk.call(self._w, "delete", items)**

```python
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import *

def GetValue(event):
    e1.delete(0, END)
    e2.delete(0, END)
    e3.delete(0, END)
    e4.delete(0, END)
    row_id = listBox.selection()[0]
    select = listBox.set(row_id)
    e1.insert(0,select['id'])
    e2.insert(0,select['empname'])
    e3.insert(0,select['mobile'])
    e4.insert(0,select['salary'])


def Add():
    studid = e1.get()
    studname = e2.get()
    coursename = e3.get()
    feee = e4.get()

    mysqldb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="payroll")
    mycursor=mysqldb.cursor()

    try:
       sql = "INSERT INTO  registation (id,empname,mobile,salary) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
       val = (studid,studname,coursename,feee)
       mycursor.execute(sql, val)
       mysqldb.commit()
       lastid = mycursor.lastrowid
       messagebox.showinfo("information", "Employee inserted successfully...")
       e1.delete(0, END)
       e2.delete(0, END)
       e3.delete(0, END)
       e4.delete(0, END)
       e1.focus_set()
    except Exception as e:
       print(e)
       mysqldb.rollback()
       mysqldb.close()


def update():
    studid = e1.get()
    studname = e2.get()
    coursename = e3.get()
    feee = e4.get()
    mysqldb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="payroll")
    mycursor=mysqldb.cursor()

    try:
       sql = "Update  registation set empname= %s,mobile= %s,salary= %s where id= %s"
       val = (studname,coursename,feee,studid)
       mycursor.execute(sql, val)
       mysqldb.commit()
       lastid = mycursor.lastrowid
       messagebox.showinfo("information", "Record Updateddddd successfully...")

       e1.delete(0, END)
       e2.delete(0, END)
       e3.delete(0, END)
       e4.delete(0, END)
       e1.focus_set()

    except Exception as e:

       print(e)
       mysqldb.rollback()
       mysqldb.close()

def delete():
    studid = e1.get()

    mysqldb=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="",database="payroll")
    mycursor=mysqldb.cursor()

    try:
       sql = "delete from registation where id = %s"
       val = (studid,)
       mycursor.execute(sql, val)
       mysqldb.commit()
       lastid = mycursor.lastrowid
       messagebox.showinfo("information", "Record Deleteeeee successfully...")

       e1.delete(0, END)
       e2.delete(0, END)
       e3.delete(0, END)
       e4.delete(0, END)
       e1.focus_set()

    except Exception as e:

       print(e)
       mysqldb.rollback()
       mysqldb.close()

def show():
        listBox.delete(0,END)
        mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="payroll")
        mycursor = mysqldb.cursor()
        mycursor.execute("SELECT id,empname,mobile,salary FROM registation")
        records = mycursor.fetchall()
        print(records)


        for i, (id,stname, course,fee) in enumerate(records, start=1):
            listBox.insert("", "end", values=(id, stname, course, fee))
            mysqldb.close()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x500")
global e1
global e2
global e3
global e4

tk.Label(root, text="Employee Registation", fg="red", font=(None, 30)).place(x=300, y=5)

tk.Label(root, text="Employee ID").place(x=10, y=10)
Label(root, text="Employee Name").place(x=10, y=40)
Label(root, text="Mobile").place(x=10, y=70)
Label(root, text="Salary").place(x=10, y=100)

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.place(x=140, y=10)

e2 = Entry(root)
e2.place(x=140, y=40)

e3 = Entry(root)
e3.place(x=140, y=70)

e4 = Entry(root)
e4.place(x=140, y=100)

Button(root, text="Add",command = Add,height=3, width= 13).place(x=30, y=130)
Button(root, text="update",command = update,height=3, width= 13).place(x=140, y=130)
Button(root, text="Delete",command = delete,height=3, width= 13).place(x=250, y=130)
Button(root, text="View Latest",command = show,height=3, width= 13).place(x=250+110, y=130)

cols = ('id', 'empname', 'mobile','salary')
listBox = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=cols, show='headings' )

for col in cols:
    listBox.heading(col, text=col)
    listBox.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
    listBox.place(x=10, y=200)

show()
listBox.bind('<Double-Button-1>',GetValue)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the full error that you are getting? Please read how to provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: There is a lot of code that doesn't seem to be necessary to reproduce this problem. Please try to reduce the code down to a [mcve].

Comment: `listBox` is a `Treeview` widget and you need to use `listBox.delete(*listBox.get_children())` to clear it. `delete(0, END)` is for `Listbox` widget.